# NameError: uninitialized constant Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am trying to create a blog in rails and my first model name is post

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base


  validates :title, presence: true

  has_many :comments

end
```

if i try to create p= Post.new in irb terminal i am getting below error.

```
rb(main):001:0> post= Post.new                                                                                                                                                                          
NameError: uninitialized constant Post 


        from (irb):1                                                                                                                                                                                     
        from /home/action/.parts/opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `irb` terminal, you need to use rails console, run this command in your terminal

```
rails console
```